# Can I use a =CELL("address" as a reference to define where VBA writes for me?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a button on a worksheet which will input today's date in the first empty cell in a row which is designated by a drop down list.

I have the dropdown set up.
I have a column (C) which designates the address of the first empty cell in each row. C11 reads $J$11, C12 reads $K$12, C13 reads $J$13.
I have a seperate cell (B2) that just references which input cell, based on what the dropdown list is currently set on.

B1=employee name (Referencing the drop down on another sheet)

B2=INDEX(C4:C100,MATCH($B$1,DatabaseTable[[#All],[Combined Name]],0)) (This finds the row, in this case, 12 and repeats the data in column C.)

C12=CELL("address",INDEX(DatabaseTable[@],0,B12)) (This outputs the the next cell address to write in this row.)

B12=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(DatabaseTable[@]),0),0) (This tells me which column contains the first blank in the row.)

So, the specific question I have (unless someone can tell me a smarter way) is, how do I tell VBA to select the cell address from B2 (Which currently reads $k$12, but can change to anything, based on the drop down), and then write today's date in that cell? (I can figure out the writing part, just need to know how to select a cell based on the cell address output)

Thanks in advance for any guidance anyone can offer!

Comment: That's basically the job of the [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474B3A3A-8A26-4F44-B491-92B6306FA261). But I'm sure you know about it in view of what you're doing, so what did I miss?

Comment: Or in VBA, You can indirect like this `Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Range("B2").Value2)`

Comment: Fantastic! You're my hero... I'm terribly lost in VBA still, so I really need jumpstarts like that to get moving. Thanks for the save!!

Comment: Have a nice VBA journey. The more you get into it, the more you'll love it :)